# Can anyone identify this app notification

Tags: applications, samsung, notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, app-icons

I have been searching a lot, and, I am unable to identify this app on the notification bar as showed in the image. The icon with a blue circle and a rabbit on it. If anyone can recognize it, that will be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: If you pull the notification bar don't you see which app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the Notification for the app named [Turbo VPN - Unlimited Free VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.vpn.unblock.proxy.turbovpn&hl=en).

- VPN proxy
- unblock sites
- WiFi hotspot secure
- protect privacy.